# Invalid reference to table while order_by applied

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have the SqlAlchemy data model (other fields is missed):

```
class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'region'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class District(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'district'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    region_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey(Region.id))
    region = relationship(Region)
```

and build this query:

```
session.query(District)\
    .options(joinedload(District.region))\
    .order_by(Region.name, Region.id)\
    .slice(0, 25)
```

The query emits an error `ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "region"`. After investigation raw SQL reason of the error was found. `ORDER BY` clause is non correct:

```
SELECT district.id AS district_id, 
    district.name AS district_name, 
    district.region_id AS district_region_id, 
    region_1.id AS region_1_id
FROM district 
LEFT OUTER JOIN region AS region_1 ON region_1.id = district.region_id 
ORDER BY region.name, region.id
LIMIT 25
```

Into `ORDER BY` clause uses `region` instead of correct alias `region_1` and this raises an error.

How to build correct query in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to `sqlalchemy` documentation [The Zen of Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#the-zen-of-eager-loading)

They describe exactly your problem, and the solution, which would be:

```
In [10]:
    ​
q = session.query(District)\
    .join(District.region)\
    .options(joinedload(District.region))\
    .order_by(Region.name, Region.id)\
    .slice(0, 25)
​
print(q)
​
SELECT district.id AS district_id, district.region_id AS district_region_id, district.name AS district_name, region_1.id AS region_1_id, region_1.name AS region_1_name 
FROM district JOIN region ON region.id = district.region_id LEFT OUTER JOIN region AS region_1 ON region_1.id = district.region_id ORDER BY region.name, region.id
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

(I had to add the names to the classes you posted by the way).

Relevant quote:

> What we see above is that our usage of Query.join() is to supply JOIN
>   clauses we’d like to use in subsequent query criterion, whereas our
>   usage of joinedload() only concerns itself with the loading of the
>   User.addresses collection, for each User in the result. In this case,
>   the two joins most probably appear redundant - which they are.

(Replace `User.addresses` by `District.region` in your case).

And if you follow the link you can make it again in one join like this:

```
In [15]:

from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased, outerjoin, contains_eager
​
ralias = aliased(Region)
​
q2 = session.query(District).\
    outerjoin(ralias, District.region).\
    options(contains_eager(District.region, alias=ralias)). \
    order_by(Region.name, Region.id).\
    slice(0, 25)
​
print(q2)
​
SELECT region_1.id AS region_1_id, region_1.name AS region_1_name, district.id AS district_id, district.region_id AS district_region_id, district.name AS district_name 
FROM district LEFT OUTER JOIN region AS region_1 ON region_1.id = district.region_id ORDER BY region.name, region.id
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

Hope it helps.